# Beamer subfig captions without prefixes

Tags: beamer, captions, subfig

I am using the [`subfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package in Beamer to stack two images on top of each other. I'm using `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}` to get rid of the figure prefixes, but I am having trouble adding captions. My goal is two images (stacked, not side-by-side), with a caption under each image, but no prefix ("(a)") on the captions.

I'm trying to follow [the example in Section 5.3 in the subfig docs](https://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf), and here are the troubles I am having:

Here, the caption is split across two lines (and the second caption is gone, probably off the slide?). I also would like the images closer together (`\label{fig:a}} \vspace{1em}` does not change the output).

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{C:/Users/me/Desktop/Capture.jpg} 
\label{fig:a}} 
\caption look at dis face \\
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{C:/Users/me/Desktop/Capture.jpg} 
\label{fig:b}} 
\caption feed me
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And in this effort, the prefixes are back and the caption is on the bottom. I am trying for something like the first effort above, with a caption under each figure.

```
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{C:/Users/me/Desktop/Capture.jpg} 
\label{fig:a}} \\
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{C:/Users/me/Desktop/Capture.jpg} 
\label{fig:b}} 
\caption[]{ \subref{fig:a} look at dis face \subref{fig:b} feed me}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: What about `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image} \label{fig:a}
\caption{look at dis face}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image} \label{fig:b}
\caption{feed me}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`?

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Currently, the documentclass is missing and you include images, that are not available to others. You could for example replace "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Capture.jpg"  with `example-image`. Apart from that, you should also enclose the caption text in a set of `{}`. So, `\caption{look at dis face}` instead of `\caption look at dis face` should fix the issue of the text being split into two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the following image?

[image]

With `\subcaptionbox` defined in the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{subcaption}{size=\tiny}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.5ex, labelformat=empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{look at dis face}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}}

\subcaptionbox{feed me}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```